# Eclipse smart home designer

Tags: java, eclipse, openhab

I´m trying to program switchable lights with openhab. My script in the shell works perfect but I can´t open the shell comand in my eclipse programm.

astro.sitemap:

```
    sitemap astro label="Home"{
        Text label="Wohnzimmer" icon=firstfloor{
            Frame label="Funksteckdosen Gruppe"{
                Switch item=poweroutletASwitch
            }

            }
                            Text label="Draußen" icon=garden {
                            Frame {
                    Default item=Sunrise_Time
                    Default item=Sunset_Time 

                }
                Frame{
                    Text item=Temperature
                    Text item=Dimensionless
                    Text item=MoonPhase
                  }    

                  }
          }
```

poweroutlets.items:

```
    Group grp_poweroutlets "Funksteckdosen Gruppe" <poweroutlet>
    String poweroutletASwitch "Funksteckdose A" <poweroutlet> [ "Switchable" 
    ] { channel="exec:command:poweroutletA-control", autoupdate="true" }
```

poweroutlets.things

```
    Thing exec:command:poweroutletA-control [ 
    command="/opt/433Utils/RPi_utils/run.sh  A %2$s", interval=0, 
    autorun=true ]
```

Any advice?